Dropdown list is not scrollable in mobile devices
I am working on a Nextjs app and I am using shadcn and tailwindcss for styling. The issue is that I have a component that is not scrollable in mobile devices (it is not touchable).
This is my child component:
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverTrigger,
  PopoverContent,
} from "@/components/ui/popover"; 
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"; 
import {
  Command,
  CommandInput,
  CommandList,
  CommandEmpty,
  CommandGroup,
  CommandItem
} from "@/components/ui/command"; 
import { Check, ChevronsUpDown } from "lucide-react"; 
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"; 

export default function DynamicSelector({
  options,
  selectedValue,
  setSelectedValue,
  placeholder,
}) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Popover open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
      <PopoverTrigger asChild>
        <Button
          variant="outline"
          role="combobox"
          aria-expanded={open}
          className="w-[200px] justify-between flex-1"
        >
          {selectedValue ? options.find(option => option.value === selectedValue)?.label : placeholder}
          <ChevronsUpDown className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50" />
        </Button>
      </PopoverTrigger>
      <PopoverContent className="max-w-[300px] p-0 overflow-y-auto h-auto">
        <Command role="listbox">
          <CommandInput placeholder={`Buscar ${placeholder.toLowerCase()}...`} />
          <CommandList className="overflow-y-scroll h-auto">
            <CommandEmpty>No se encontraron opciones.</CommandEmpty>
            <CommandGroup>
              {options.map((option) => (
                <CommandItem
                  key={option.value}
                  onSelect={() => {
                    setSelectedValue(option.value);
                    setOpen(false);
                  }}
                >
                  <Check
                    className={cn(
                      "mr-2 h-4 w-4",
                      selectedValue === option.value ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"
                    )}
                  />
                  {option.label}
                </CommandItem>
              ))}
            </CommandGroup>
          </CommandList>
        </Command>
      </PopoverContent>
    </Popover>
  );
}

And this is a fragment of the parent component:
{step === 4 && !isLoading && (
          <div className="dynamicselector p-4 border-t border-border flex gap-2 fixed bottom-0 left-0 right-0">
            <DynamicSelector
              className="border border-gray-300 rounded-md px-4 py-2 mb-2 overflow-y-auto"
              selectedValue={selectedBank}
              setSelectedValue={setSelectedBank}
              options={BANCOS.map((banco) => ({
                value: banco.Codigo,
                label: banco.Descripcion,
              }))}
              placeholder={"Selecciona tu banco"}
            />
            <Button
              onClick={() => processInput(selectedBank)}
              className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg"
            >
              <Send className="h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
          </div>
        )}

I´ve tried using overflow-y-auto, overflow-y-scroll, touch-* and other properties but I was not even close of making this component scrollable in mobile devices.
I do not know if this is a shadcn issue (which I don´t think so), or is just something I am doing wrong (I am clueless).
The thing is although a scrollbar appears in my component when I simulate a mobile device using the devtools, I am not being able to scroll, I´ve also tried directly from a phone and neither did scroll.
